# Not able to upload apk to play console for first time

Tags: apk, google-play-console

You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint: [ SHA1: abc] and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint: [ SHA1:xyz]

Comment: When you enrolled in Play Signing, did you provide an upload certificate? If so, you need to sign your APK with the keystore that was used to generate that upload certificate.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of step did you follow? please tell it elaborately that can help people to give you a proper solution. I think this step will help you to solve your problem. Build a signed apk with signing key from android studio build option. then go to the project folder, then goo app->relase-> you will find your apk file or aab file please try to upload that.